# "Lvalue" и "incomplete type"

Tags: c++

Наткнулся на описание `rvalue` и `lvalue` в стандарте:

> Class rvalues can have cv-qualified types; non-class rvalues always have cv-unqualified types. Rvalues
>   shall always have complete types or the void type; in addition to these types, lvalues can also have incomplete types.

Что в данном контексте означает последнее выражение

> lvalues can also have incomplete types?

Под `incomplete type` я понимаю классы, которые объявлены, но не определены (или пока не определены).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В пункте 3.9 раскрывается значение "incomplete type"

> A class that has been declared but not defined, or an array of unknown size or of incomplete element type, is an incompletely-defined object type.43 Incompletely-defined object types and the void types are incomplete types (3.9.1). Objects shall not be defined to have an incomplete type.

То есть, классы без реализации, массивы неизвестного размера или массивы "неполностью объявленного типа".

Comment: Только непонятно, что значит lvalue может иметь incomplete type? Насколько я знаю, lvalue - это то, что может стоять в левой части присваивания или от чего можно взять адрес (если не вдаваться в подробности). Как тогда у объекта с неполным типом можно взять адрес, если и сам то такой объект нельзя создать?

Comment: Если бы объект нельзя было создать, тогда проект нельзя было бы скомпилировать. 

В данном случае имеется ввиду, что если есть переменная указатель  на объект какого то класса, и больше ничего из этого класса не используется, то в **данной точке кода** класс будет объявлен не полностью, но это не мешает компилятору скомпилировать файл (другое дело, слинковать).

Comment: KoVadim, но какую роль здесь, в таком случае, играет lvalue? Ведь такой указатель можно из функции возвратить, т.е. получается, что он в таком случае будет уже rvalue, а это не соответствует "Rvalues shall always have complete types or the void type". Что-то мне кажется, что я не в том направлении размышляю.. )

Comment: @Waylander123, указатель на объект (экземпляр) какого-то класса != сам класс или объект класса

Comment: Если нужно возвращать с функции, то наверно внутри функции придется создать объект? или просто "пробросить указатель". В первом случае класс все таки придется реализовать полностью, а в другом - чем он отличается от просто передачи int?

Comment: С указателями понятно, но только там написано просто "incomplete type", а не "pointer to incomplete type", и в первом случае объект как раз не получится создать. Что значит "в дополнение к этим типам lvalues могут также иметь incomplete types"?. Можете привести пример, когда неполный тип может использоваться как lvalue, но не может как rvalue?